# The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. newtonsoft

Tags: c#, asp.net, dll, reference

I know this has been asked countless times before, but I have searched all over the place and I haven't found a solution.

I initially download a newtonsoft package from the nuget package manager.

I first searched all 3 projects' csproj references - there was one reference pointing to an older version. I then did a find and replace, pointing them all to the same version in the package folder created automatically by VS. It didn't help.

I then added a  `<SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>` to all the newtonsoft references, and removed all culture and version information from the references. This didn't help

I have deleted all project bin folder and that didn't help. I have deleted all asp.net temp folders and that didn't help. I tried to delete the newtonsoft dll from the gac by calling:
`gacutil.exe /u Newtonsoft.Json.dll`, but it didn't find a dll to remove.

I redownloaded the dlls from http://json.codeplex.com/ and pointed all references to the same dll.

I have also cleaned and rebuilt.

Is there anything else I can do to get rid of this error?

Comment: Json.NET uses the assembly version setting to indicate the minimum .NET framework it requires - it does not indicate the Json.NET version ([see here for an explanation](http://james.newtonking.com/archive/2012/04/04/json-net-strong-naming-and-assembly-version-numbers)). I guess, your different projects use different .NET framework targets and thus reference different Newtonsoft.Json.dll's for those .NET framework targets. (If you don't know what i mean, just [download the Json.NET ZIP archive](http://james.newtonking.com/json) and look into its Bin folder with the different libraries.)

Comment: If you made sure that your projects indeed reference the very same DLL file of Json.NET (your question seems to indicate this), do your projects incorporate other libraries/assemblies which would depend on Json.NET?

Comment: I need to make a correction about my first comment here. I just noticed that since Json.NET 6.0.x, the assembly version 6.0.0.0 is used across all Json.NET DLLs for the different .NET framework targets. Although what i said about the assembly version number remains true for the Json.NET 5'er versions, it does **not** apply anymore to Json.NET 6.0.x. Sorry, if this created confustion...